# Python: get correct link with dynamic URLs in Flask with url_for()

Tags: python, html, flask, url, jinja2

I have html template, and python function(driver_links), my functional work but I have the wrong link

**html template (driver_id.html):**

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('driver_links', driver_id=key[0]) }}">{{key[0]}}</a>
```

**function:**

```py
@app.route("/report/drivers/<driver_id>")
def driver_links(driver_id):

    context = {

        "report": sort_asc_desc('data', 'asc'),
        "test": driver_id
    }
    return render_template('driver_id.html', **context)
```

**wrong link I have:** http://127.0.0.1:5000/report/drivers/SVF

if I change @app.route in function(driver_links) to:

```py
@app.route("/report/drivers/")
```

I get a correct link, but function doesn't work

**example correct link:** http://127.0.0.1:5000/report/drivers/?driver_id=SVF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose between [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) or url parameters.
If you use the former, the required, extracted parameter is passed as a variable to the function.

```py
@app.route("/report/drivers/<driver_id>")
def driver_links(driver_id):
    # ...
```

With the latter, you have to ask for the **optional** parameter from the dictionary [`request.args`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Request.args) and no arguments are passed to the function.

```py
from flask import request

@app.route("/report/drivers/")
def driver_links():
    driver_id = request.args.get('driver_id')
    # ...
```

Note that you can specify a default value and a type conversion here. You can find the documentation for this [here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get).